# NSNotificationCenter "bad instruction" xcode6

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying to add a simple keyboard notification, but receive a "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" error whenever I run the code. Any help is appreciated.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)


    func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        var info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()

        var keyboardHeight:CGFloat =  keyboardSize.height - 40

        var animationDuration:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as CGFloat

        var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0);
        self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    }



    func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell us which line the exception is thrown at ?

Comment: exception thrown at the top line ( thanks for quick response :) )

Comment: Where are you adding the notifications?

Comment: im adding them at the top of my code, before viewDidLoad()

Comment: @säculnój you mean inside viewdidload() right?

Comment: correct. thats what i meant to say

Comment: its working for me i will add a sample code...

Comment: @säculnój  i have done a sample project in xcode with this and the notification is getting executed.only thing that i need to check is to remove observer before adding them in view didload.

Comment: ok i dont get an error anymore ( ty ), but still dont "receive" any notification, even when add println("test") to the func

Comment: the problem was i didnt import CoreData. why do we have to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your top two lines from :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

to :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
```

Notice the Selector("nameoftheFunction:") syntax in swift

Comment: hmm, i tried that, still throwing same exception tho.

Comment: Can you paste here the content of the console output ?

Comment: only output is (llbd)

Comment: where are those two lines called ?

Comment: called inside viewdidload().

Answer (score 0):

import UIKit

import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
   var info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()

    var keyboardHeight:CGFloat =  keyboardSize.height - 40

    var animationDuration:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as CGFloat

    var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}



func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
     self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

}